# GWT reduce compiled javascript size

Tags: javascript, gwt

I have found that the size of the compiled JavaScript grows faster than I had expected. Adding a few lines of Java code to my project can increase the script size in several Kbs.

At the moment my compiled project weights 1Mb. I'm not using any external libraries except for those for MVP (Activities & Places) , testing (JUnit) and logging.

I would like to know if there are any coding practices/recommendations to keep the compiled script as small as possible. I'm not refering to code splitting, but to coding techniques or patterns that can make the compiled JavaScript effectively smaller.

Many thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

GWT uses a "pay as you go" design philosophy, and since you're not allowed to use reflection the compiler can statically prove (on a method-by-method basis) that a section of code is "reachable", and eliminate those that are not.  For example, if you never use the remove() method on ArrayList, then that code does not get included in the resulting JavaScript.

If you are seeing several kilobyte jumps with the addition of just a few lines, it probably means that you've introduced the use of a new type (and possibly one that depends on other new types) that you had not yet been using.   It might also mean that you've made a change to send this new type "over the wire" back to the server, in which case a GWT generator had to include JavaScript for marshaling that type, and any new types that are reachable via its "has-a" and "is-a" references.

So if it were me, I would begin there:  when you catch a 2-line change making a multi-kilobyte increase, start by looking at the types and asking whether it is a type that you have used before, and whether you're sending a new type over the wire, and whether that type also depends on other types under the hood.

One final thought: in Ray Ryan's 2009 presentation at Google I/O he mentioned a superstition that he had picked up from the GWT compiler team, where they recommended against using generic types (I'm not speaking of Java Generics here, but rather supertypes) as RPC arguments & return values.  In particular, instead of having your RPC call take or return a Map, have it take or return a HashMap instead.  The belief is that the GWT generator can then narrow the amount of serialization code that it has to create at compile time (because it could, for example, refrain from generating serialization code for a TreeMap).

I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 Very good answer. One additional recommendation: You can use the [Compile Report](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompileReport.html) to find out exactly, which packages/classes are responsible for a large growth in your code size.

Answer (score 4):

GWT creates different output versions for each supported browser, so when you say the project size is 1MB are you then referring to the combined size of these ? (each browser only download's the one it actually needs).

I have tried to experiment with the generated output when using various inheritance/class/generics constructs. Unfortunately the extra complexity introduced far outweighs the small size improvements gained (when fx. dumping generics).

I have been on some large GWT projects (+50.000 lines) and have found that code obfuscating coupled with turning on compression on the web server to be the simplest most effective way to minimize the downloads. If this does not shrink the code enough, then look into GWT's  [compilation report](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompileReport.html) which you can use to pinpoint potential problematic classes and places to insert code splitting.

Comment: No, it's aprox 1Mb for each browser. I agree that compression is the most effective way to reduce the download size.

Comment: +1 for code splitting. I think for big project this feature is really important.