# GWT CodeSplitting

Tags: java, gwt

I'm having some Problems with Reducing the Initial download size in a GWT project,
according to the compile Report ,most of the Download codes are from RPC type_serialized files , is there any way to breakdown these files as by only including important RPC files ?
and I'm also new to Code Splitting , also wanted to know any other ways of reducing the Initial Download size ,

Thank You !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778664/gwt-how-can-i-reduce-the-size-of-code-serializers-for-rpc-calls

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411600/gwt-reduce-compiled-javascript-size